# Accessor in interface cannot be delimited by comma

Tags: typescript

The following is a parsing error:

```
interface I {
  get x(): number,
  //             ^-- cannot be comma
}
```

> '{' expected.ts(1005)

The alternatives, using a semicolon, or nothing, are fine:

```
interface I {
  get x(): number;
  get y(): number
}
```

I can't immediately see, how this is unavoidable in the grammer, so why?

The [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#separate-write-types-on-properties) didn't seem to mention anything about this limitation. It is especially painful, if the linter enforces use of commas as delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a minor oversight in TS, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49544 for tracking.

Answer (score -1):

```
interface I {
  get x(): number;
  get y(): number; // <- Add a semicolon on each field
}
```